# Unable to access JSON content after reading from a file

Tags: jquery, json, file

I've spent hours and hours searching for reading JSON file using JS. 
The closest tut I found was this https://gist.github.com/zuch/6224600.

cells.json:

```
{
  "cells": [
    {
      "img": "img/singlestitch_thumb.jpg",
      "url": "http://www.google.com",
      "description": "an interactive 'kite' sketch based on a favorite letter[requires java]",
      "smallwin": true
    },
    {
      "img": "img/text3d_thumb2.jpg",
      "url": "http://www.yahoo.com",
      "description": "animated custom font design in 3d (featured on the 'processing' site)[requires java]",
      "smallwin": true
    },
    {
      "img": "img/jazzer_thumb.jpg",
      "url": "http://flickr.com",
      "description": "a 3d musician that 'plays along' with arbitrary audio tracks[req. javajsyn]",
      "smallwin": true
    }
  ]
}
```

testjson.html:

```
var cells = [];

$.getJSON( "cells.json", function( json ) {

    $.each(json, function(i, lv_1) {

        $.each(lv_1, function(j, lv_2) {

            $.each(lv_2, function(k, lv_3) {
                //console.log( k + ':' + lv_3 + '' );
                //console.log( JSON.parse(k + ':' + lv_3 + '') );
                cells.push( k + ':' + lv_3 + '' );
            });
        }); 
    });
});

console.log(cells);
```

This is the error.

> console.log( cells[0].url ); // TypeError: cells[0] is undefined

I cannot access the element within.

Attached is the zip file package. You can use Firefox or setup a local server to test with.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/nmfq98s7raep92r/json%20test.zip?dl=0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are making this much harder than necessary. Once you have the data, you can simply use it (though perhaps I'm missing something):

```
$.getJSON("cells.json", function (json) {

    var cells = json.cells;
    console.log( cells[0].url ); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your JSON only has 2 levels, so the third `each` will fail. Secondly, your first loop should use `json.cells`. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("cells.json", function (json) {
    $.each(json.cells, function (i, lv_1) {
        $.each(lv_1, function (j, lv_2) {
            cells.push(j + ':' + lv_2 + '');
        });
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vogoxux7/)

Comment: That's never going to work as you're creating an array, not an object. If you want an object you need to completely change your logic

Comment: Thanks! Is there any tutorial for this? Or what is the best way to read it? I just want to read the first 'url', first 'img' and then the second, etc.

Comment: Well your response is already coming through as an object, so it's already taken care of, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/vogoxux7/2/

Comment: Thanks again! It works. But how can I access the data? I tried to make it a function but it seems like an deferred object. http://jsfiddle.net/m0e7expd/ Or is there any better practice to access the element?

Comment: Why did you remove the accepted answer here? The one you have now accepted is the same as in the fiddle I added in the comments?